# Could the spin of a Black Hole give us insight into the size of the core?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, singularities

As we know the conservation of angular momentum seems to be rather true and applies to black holes as well. We know that they spin and we also know the relationship between angular velocity and radius.

So let's say we happen to find a star that will collapse into a black hole. We know its mass, spin etc and can measure the spin after the black hole has formed. Wouldn't that enable us to give a rough estimate into how large the core is?

Sure there are big uncertainties like how much of the angular momentum went into the black hole rather than being "ejected" and how massive it exactly is etc. But in principle, that should give us a number which is vaguely in the right ball park. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "core"?

Comment: Black holes are not known to have a 'core', unlike stars, planets and neutron stars. What goes inside of them is a mystery which is only expected to be cleared up once we have a theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: I'd recommend reading about the [No Hair Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).

Comment: “*we also know the relationship between angular velocity and radius*” - In the simplest case of a non-spinning black hole, the radial distance from the horizon to the origin is zero. The radius inside the horizon measures time, not distance. (For a spinning black hole the same is true between the outer and inner horizons.)